# Подключение к HTTPS через System.Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, сокет, https

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(Host, 80);
```

Подключаюсь так к HTTPS серверу но он не дает доступ, можно ли как нибудь используя Socket получать данные веб страницы?

Comment: А обязательно использовать сокет? Есть нормальный вариант с `WebClient` и потом данные в поток `Stream` считать.

Comment: К сожалению да, обязательно...

Comment: Тогда как насчёт этого? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945724/how-to-receive-http-messages-using-socket

Comment: Я не очень понимаю как это мне поможет с HTTPS, не могли бы вы мне продемонстрировать пример с реализацией?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx 
Проверил код отсюда, вроде, работает и возвращает результат запроса

Comment: Попробовал код из примера, к сожалению при попытке подключения к HTTPS серверу получил 301 ошибку.

Comment: Жесть, конечно. В 2018 году слать https запросы на сырых сокетах -_-

Comment: @Suvitruf Мне кажется здесь в целях ознакомления идет. Человек хочет понять как работает https протокол, да и в целом сокеты. Так что как по мне... Затея хорошая (в ознакомление конечно) и самому было бы интересно на эту реализацию глянуть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в ознакомительных целях нужно начинать с http, чтоб с SslStream не мучиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите без использования `SslStream`, тогда придется писать несколько тысяч строк кода для того, что бы поддерживать TLS. А ниже самый простой способ:

```
string host = "ru.stackoverflow.com";

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(host, 443);

SslStream tls = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(socket));
tls.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

string request = "GET / HTTP/1.0" + Environment.NewLine +
    "Host: " + host + Environment.NewLine +
    Environment.NewLine;

tls.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request));

using (var sr = new StreamReader(tls, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, но к сожалению ReadToEnd выполняется более 20 секунд, возможно ли ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: @Wanderer Странно, каждый раз более 20 сек конкретно на этой строчке? В меня все норм (если запрашиваю страницу стековерфлов).

Comment: Примерно, от 20 до 60, может быть это из за того что сокет не закрывает соединение? Если читать блоками то первые N блоков читаем нормально (мс) а последний тормозит 20+ секунд.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что сервер открывает `Keep-Alive` соединение, и не разрывает его в конце (чего требует `StreamReader`). Попробуйте явно указать в заголовке, что вам не нужно такое поведение.